# Sony Tablet S ADB Connection Issues

Tags: android, adb

I'm following Sony's instructions on connecting my Sony Tablet S to my computer through ADB.

However, when typing:

```
adb devices
```

I don't see any connected devices.

I've tried manually adding the hardware IDs to the USB driver and using an automated driver installer.  I've also added the correct hexadecimal code to *adb_usb.ini*:

```
0x54c
```

For some reason, most of the pages that I've been to have a completely different hardware ID than my Sony Tablet S.  The ones that I'm seeing online are the following:

```
USB\VID_054C&PID_04D2&MI_01
```

Mine looks like this:

```
USB\VID_054C&PID_05B3&REV_0100
USB\VID_054C&PID_05B3
```

I'm wondering if that means anything.  I have rooted the tablet once before, but I've restored the root and have restored to factory settings.  I wouldn't think that would change that hardware ID though.

I changed the default hardware ID in the *android_winusb.inf* file to match my hardware IDs but nothing still shows up in ADB.

Any thoughts?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: you are sure usb debugging option is enabled in your device ?

Comment: Hi Rilwan -- I verified the tablet's settings, and yes, it is enabled.  Thanks!